# Memory Leaking Android

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks, locale, leakcanary

Do you guys have any suggestion what can cause this memory leak that I got from the Leak Canary?
Below is the description I am getting from the report.

Steps to reproduce are, In the Settings menu, click on the switch which will perform the theme change, after this action, leaking happening. Below this I will provide the code piece from the SettingsFragmentClass. Any help would be most welcomed guys.

Basically issue is happening when this line is being called.
**AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)**

```
┬───
│ GC Root: Global variable in native code
│
├─ android.graphics.animation.RenderNodeAnimator instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 1.1 MB in 16344 objects
│    ↓ RenderNodeAnimator.mTarget
│                         ~~~~~~~
├─ android.graphics.RenderNode instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 1.1 MB in 16274 objects
│    ↓ RenderNode.mHostView
│                 ~~~~~~~~~
├─ com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial instance
│    Leaking: YES (View.mContext references a destroyed activity)
│    Retaining 1.1 MB in 16272 objects
│    View not part of a window view hierarchy
│    View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
│    View.mID = R.id.null
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    mContext instance of com.flixeron.my_passkeeper.main.MainActivity with
│    mDestroyed = true
│    ↓ View.mContext
╰→ com.flixeron.my_passkeeper.main.MainActivity instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.flixeron.
​     my_passkeeper.main.MainActivity received Activity#onDestroy() callback
​     and Activity#mDestroyed is true)
​     Retaining 251.2 kB in 5956 objects
​     key = 3c074833-b927-4971-b2b5-0a77b9e68bde
​     watchDurationMillis = 5216
​     retainedDurationMillis = 215
​     mApplication instance of com.flixeron.my_passkeeper.main.MainApplication
​     mBase instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper
METADATA
Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 31
Build.MANUFACTURER: Xiaomi
LeakCanary version: 2.7
App process name: com.flixeron.my_passkeeper
Stats: LruCache[maxSize=3000,hits=6345,misses=185335,hitRate=3%]
RandomAccess[bytes=9694284,reads=185335,travel=115234430872,range=38720254,size=
46574102]
Heap dump reason: 7 retained objects, app is visible
Analysis duration: 15049 ms
```

> Fragment Class

```
class SettingsFragment : Fragment() {

private val cardViewModel: CardViewModel by viewModel()

private var bindingProp: FragmentSettingsBinding? = null
private val binding get() = bindingProp!!

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    bindingProp = FragmentSettingsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    setTextLockTime()
    configureScreenShoots()
    themeSettings()

    // changing dark/light mode
    binding.switchTheme.setOnClickListener {
        if (!PreferenceProvider.darkMode) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
            PreferenceProvider.darkMode = true
            binding.imageViewTheme.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_dark_mode)
        } else {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
            PreferenceProvider.darkMode = false
            binding.imageViewTheme.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_light_mode)
        }
    }

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    bindingProp = null
  }
}
```

> Xml file

```
                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/switchTheme"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewChangeTheme"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textViewChangeTheme">

                    <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
                        android:id="@+id/switchTheme1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/switchTheme"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/switchTheme"
                        android:scaleX="1.3"
                        android:scaleY="1.3"/>

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Updated leak canary

````
┬───
│ GC Root: System class
│
├─ android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager class
│    Leaking: NO (InputMethodManager↓ is not leaking and a class is never
│    leaking)
│    ↓ static InputMethodManager.sInstance
├─ android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager instance
│    Leaking: NO (DecorView↓ is not leaking and InputMethodManager is a
│    singleton)
│    ↓ InputMethodManager.mCurRootView
├─ android.view.ViewRootImpl instance
│    Leaking: NO (DecorView↓ is not leaking)
│    mContext instance of com.android.internal.policy.DecorContext, wrapping
│    activity com.flixeron.my_passkeeper.main.MainActivity with mDestroyed =
│    false
│    ViewRootImpl#mView is not null
│    mWindowAttributes.mTitle = "com.flixeron.my_passkeeper/com.flixeron.
│    my_passkeeper.main.MainActivity"
│    mWindowAttributes.type = 1
│    ↓ ViewRootImpl.mView
├─ com.android.internal.policy.DecorView instance
│    Leaking: NO (View attached)
│    View is part of a window view hierarchy
│    View.mAttachInfo is not null (view attached)
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    mContext instance of com.android.internal.policy.DecorContext, wrapping
│    activity com.flixeron.my_passkeeper.main.MainActivity with mDestroyed =
│    false
│    ↓ View.mResources
│           ~~~~~~~~~~
├─ dev.b3nedikt.app_locale.AppLocaleResources instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 1.9 kB in 55 objects
│    context instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper
│    ↓ AppLocaleResources.context
│                         ~~~~~~~
├─ androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 274.9 kB in 6390 objects
│    mBase instance of io.github.inflationx.viewpump.ViewPumpContextWrapper
│    ContextThemeWrapper does not wrap a known Android context
│    ↓ ContextWrapper.mBase
│                     ~~~~~
├─ io.github.inflationx.viewpump.ViewPumpContextWrapper instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 270.3 kB in 6242 objects
│    mBase instance of dev.b3nedikt.app_locale.AppLocaleContextWrapper
│    ViewPumpContextWrapper does not wrap a known Android context
│    ↓ ContextWrapper.mBase
│                     ~~~~~
├─ dev.b3nedikt.app_locale.AppLocaleContextWrapper instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 270.2 kB in 6236 objects
│    mBase instance of android.app.ContextImpl
│    AppLocaleContextWrapper does not wrap a known Android context
│    ↓ ContextWrapper.mBase
│                     ~~~~~
├─ android.app.ContextImpl instance
│    Leaking: YES (ContextImpl.mOuterContext is an instance of com.flixeron.
│    my_passkeeper.main.MainActivity with Activity.mDestroyed true)
│    Retaining 268.1 kB in 6175 objects
│    mAutofillClient instance of com.flixeron.my_passkeeper.main.MainActivity
│    with mDestroyed = true
│    mOuterContext instance of com.flixeron.my_passkeeper.main.MainActivity
│    with mDestroyed = true
│    ↓ ContextImpl.mAutofillClient
╰→ com.flixeron.my_passkeeper.main.MainActivity instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.flixeron.
​     my_passkeeper.main.MainActivity received Activity#onDestroy() callback
​     and Activity#mDestroyed is true)
​     Retaining 264.2 kB in 6091 objects
​     key = 44a30066-31c8-4abb-8660-907035d18457
​     watchDurationMillis = 5229
​     retainedDurationMillis = 224
​     mApplication instance of com.flixeron.my_passkeeper.main.MainApplication
​     mBase instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper
METADATA
Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 31
Build.MANUFACTURER: Xiaomi
LeakCanary version: 2.7
App process name: com.flixeron.my_passkeeper
Count of retained yet cleared: 1 KeyedWeakReference instances
Stats: LruCache[maxSize=3000,hits=3959,misses=160418,hitRate=2%]
RandomAccess[bytes=8403631,reads=160418,travel=86543130456,range=36387679,size=4
4147138]
Heap dump reason: 6 retained objects, app is visible
Analysis duration: 11869 ms```
````

Comment: Can you show the implementation of view model?

Comment: Don't worry about the view model. I got them through out the many places. All good is with that. Basically if i remove this line AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES). Leaking is not present anymore.

Answer (score 2):

your leak is strictly related to GUI, which gets restared when user change theme with your option

conider releasing GUI-related objects by releasing binded `View`s when `Fragment` gets destroyed (and further/soon will be recreated with new theme)

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
    bindingProp = null
    super.onDestroyView()
}
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for answering. However it was my mistake for not including the onDestroy part. It was already there, I forgot to include it into the question. However because you spend time, I have upvoted your answer anyway. I think it's fair. Sad part is that issue is still there.

Comment: imho now it looks like a leak caused by `SwitchMaterial` animation implemented in google lib, and this is their fault... if there is a newer version of this dependency - import it, your problem may be already solved by lib authors. if not - you can workaround this by NOT starting a `SwitchMaterial`s animation. but it start when user clicks it... so don't allow user to toggle it, make `clickable`/`focusable`  `false` and exchange `setOnCheckedChangeListener` for simple `OnClickListener` set up on parent of switch (assuming some row on settings list)

Comment: `Activity` gets recreated anyway and default setup/gui look is probably done by one of not-posted-but-called methods in `onCreate` - in fact you don't need this animation, it won't be visible

Comment: Hmm good point man, this definitely could be the root cause then. I will adapt it to new logic now and let you know, how it behaves. Thanks once again for pointing it out.

Comment: Bro unfortunatelly, this didn't help. I have updated question, with the adapted code logic.

Comment: try set also `enabled` and `focusableInTouchMode`, also worth checking my suspecion: as you currently don't need this `SwitchMaterial` (well, only on setup for showing current state) try to remove it at all still keeping working `OnClickListener`. does leak occur then?

Comment: Bro unfortunatelly this didn't help also. I have even change the switch to be the textView, same story. I have updated answer with new leak canary that occurs after changing switch to the textView. Basically in my opinion it is related to the localization in my app. How not quite sure.